# Using lambda with JdbcTemplate query method showing ambigious error

Tags: java, lambda, sonarqube, spring-jdbc

When I compile this code it's showing 
*[ERROR] The method query(String, Object[], ResultSetExtractor) is ambiguous for the type JdbcTemplate*

```
Collection<MyType> col = getJdbcTemplate().query(someQuery, new Object[]{param},
    rs -> {
        Map<Long, MyType> map = new HashMap();
        while (rs.next()) {
        // mapping logic
        }
        return map.values();
    });
```

But if I cast `rs` to`(ResultSetExtractor<Collection<MyType>>)` it somehow compiles properly.

```
Collection<MyType> col = getJdbcTemplate().query(someQuery, new Object[]{param},
    (ResultSetExtractor<Collection<MyType>>)  rs -> {
        Map<Long, MyType> map = new HashMap();
        while (rs.next()) {
        // mapping logic
        }
        return map.values();
    });
```

But my IDE(with sonar) reports it as redundant cast, reports everything inside the lambda body as unused. I'm using jdk 1.8.0_121

Can somebody throw some light on this please, thanks

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Had a similar issue which was gone after switching to update 111/112.

Comment: The compiler might not be able to infer the type (of the lambda expression). Keep in mind that the `query` method is overloaded. Maybe a newer JDK 8 compiler would help. As a "workaround" (which also is more readable), I would either extract the lambda body to an own method and use a method reference here, or extract the whole lambda expression to a correctly typed method that simply gets called here.

Comment: it's jdk 1.8.0_121

Comment: I think you want to cast it to (RowCallbackHandler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) has 3 methods named `query`, where first argument is a `String`, and second argument is an `Object[]`:

- [`query(String sql, Object[] args, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-)
- [`query(String sql, Object[] args, RowCallbackHandler rch)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler-)
- [`query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-)

The functional interface for the third argument of the first two take a single parameter of type `ResultSet`:

- [`ResultSetExtractor.extractData(ResultSet rs)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html#extractData-java.sql.ResultSet-)
- [`RowCallbackHandler.processRow(ResultSet rs)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html#processRow-java.sql.ResultSet-)

That is why the compiler needed a little help to figure out which one you meant.

That IDE/Sonar is flawed and cannot see that cast is necessary, is just a bug.